# Can not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hbase

Im new to hbase and ive been scouring the internet for the answer to this.I believe this is a class path issue. Im running java 1.8, hadoop 3.2, and hbase 2.2. The hbase documentation says to sets

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH://home/hadoop/hbase/lib/*
```

in the ~/.bashrc file.

Similarly ive tried

```
export CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
```

(although in the version of hbase i have there was no lib directory in the the hbase directory)

I have also tried updating the hbase-env.sh, Does anyone have a definitive answer on this?

[image]

Comment: The error suggests `hbase classpath` command doesn't work. Refer  this section of the docs - https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase.mapreduce.classpath

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same errors with hbase-start.sh recently. Here are some things you may want to check:
1) Make sure JAVA_HOME in hbase-env.sh is set to the right directory (e.g. /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64).

2) Make sure you used the ".bin.tar.gz" instead of ".src.tar.gz" version of the files. https://hbase.apache.org/book.html section 2.2 says: "Do not download the file ending in src.tar.gz for now."

3) Make sure your config files are copied appropriately across all nodes without errors.